# Get InaccessibleObjectException

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I am trying to write a test to get a object. But it shows the error ->"java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader(jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader,jdk.internal.loader.URLClassPath) accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @7fc229ab". How can I fix it?

```
 @Test
public void testGetObject5() throws Exception {
    NominBeanFactory nominBeanFactory = new NominBeanFactory();
    nominBeanFactory.setApplicationContext(mock(ApplicationContext.class));
    nominBeanFactory.setMapping(new ArrayList<>());
    NominMapperValidator actualObject = nominBeanFactory.getObject();
    assertTrue(actualObject.getCache().isEmpty());
    assertNull(actualObject.getValidator());
    NominMapper nominMapper = actualObject.getNominMapper();
    assertTrue(nominMapper instanceof Nomin);
    assertTrue(((Nomin) nominMapper).defaultIntrospector() instanceof org.nomin.util.ReflectionIntrospector);
    assertTrue(((Nomin) nominMapper).isAutomappingEnabled());
    assertTrue(((Nomin) nominMapper).getMappings().isEmpty());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:
--add-opens=java.base/jdk.internal.loader=ALL-UNNAMED
to the Java-VM-Parameters.

More infos:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/migrate/migrating-jdk-8-later-jdk-releases.html#GUID-2F61F3A9-0979-46A4-8B49-325BA0EE8B66